# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data' while running a LinkedList code

Tags: python

This is a code to add a new node at the beginning of a linked list and then print the elements in the linked list. But when I run the program I get the following error in the last line when I call the ll1.print_LL() function:

**AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data'**

And here is my code:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.ref = None
        
class LL:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        
    def print_LL(self):
        if self.head is None:
            print("LL is empty")
        else:
            node = self.head
            while self.head is not None:
                print(node.data)
                node = node.ref
    
    def add_begin(self, data):
        new_node = Node(data)
        new_node.ref = self.head
        
        self.head = new_node
        
        
ll1 = LL()
ll1.add_begin(10)
ll1.add_begin(20)
ll1.print_LL()
```

I have seen a post about a similar error on StackOverflow, but I'm still confused.
Why am I getting this error in my code and how do I fix it?

Comment: `while self.head is not None:` - `self.head` will never be `None` if there are nodes in the list. You should be checking if `node.ref` is `None`. Which is to say, you go right past the end of your linked list and set `node` to `None`, which is why it doesn't have any attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Short Answer:***
Change `while self.head is not None:`
to
`while node is not None:`

***Explanation****
The error message tells you something that you might think of. It tells you that at some point you're trying to get ".data" from a None variable, which means your loops at "some point" reach None.

Now, the issue is at this part

```
 def print_LL(self):
        if self.head is None:
            print("LL is empty")
        else:
            node = self.head
            while self.head is not None:
                print(node.data)
                node = node.ref
```

Here, you are assigning node = self.head which is making the pointer point to the first element (the head), and you WANT to make the pointer move forward, which what you're doing when you said: `node=node.ref`, however, your test condition is not correct, because you're testing against self.head.

Since `self.head` is never gonna be None, it will keep looping forever, but the node will keep moving forward and return a None error because there are no more nodes.

The answer:

Change the while loop to:

```
    def print_LL(self):
        if self.head is None:
            print("LL is empty")
        else:
            node = self.head
            while node is not None:
                print(node.data)
                node = node.ref
```

Answer (score 1):

While the breaking error has been pointed out in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73698800/19708304), there is another intricacy worth considering, `add_begin()` function should be changed to:

```
      def add_begin(self,data):
        new_node = Node(data)
        if self.head is None:
          self.head = new_node
        else:
          new_node.ref = self.head
          self.head = new_node
```

.because when the first time you call `add_begin()` function, there is no value in `head` and as such the line

> `new_node.ref = self.head` is meaningless as it is assigning None value to None value.

Also it improves code readability.